# Complicated excel question regarding sorting of four columns by one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four columns grouped together. I have a fifth column that is shorter than col#4 but all it's values are within col#4. I want to sort all four columns by having col#4 become identical to col #5 (same value/length). I don't know how to do this. In the picture below, I want Col 'L' to be in the same order as Col 'N' but I want to make sure the values still match up for Columns k,l,m. Meaning the third row should have 123,ava,lol

[image]

Comment: A screen shot or example would probably help.

Comment: Can't do a screenshot because of material but I'll try to give an example. In the meantime maybe this will explain it better. I want Col #'s 1-4 to be sorted by Col #4 which will copy the order of Col #5

Comment: Hopefully my picture gives better idea.

Comment: It helps if you provide an expected output as well. In your question you write about 5 columns, in the screen shot there are only 4. If you use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to show your sample data and expected output it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct and you have Excel 365 - you can use this formula:

`=SORTBY(A2:C6,MATCH(B2:B6,E2:E6,0),1)`

`MATCH(B2:B6,E2:E6,0)` returns the new sort order - which is then applied to the matrix to sort.

[image]